# Linking a static library when compiling a C program

Tags: command-line, c, static-linking

I'm linking `*.a file` with `*.c file`, so I have used the following command:

```
gcc abc.c -l ad.a
```

(here `abc` is the C source file and ad is the static library file)

then after executing the following error message is coming.
the library `lad.a` not found.

Comment: With static libraries you don't need to use `-l`. Try `gcc abc.c libad.a`, or whatever the actual static library name is. Just pretend the library is another object file.

Comment: Otherwise, remove the extension and add the directory: `gcc abc.c -L . -lad`

Comment: I don't see any option of ANSI: `gcc -ansi -Wpedantic -std=c++11` , of course you can choose another `std`.

Answer (score 1):

To link with a library with a filename `libad.a` you link options to `gcc` should be:

```
gcc abc.c -lad
```

So you don't specify the extension, nor the starting `lib` part of the library file name.
The output file will be `a.out`. You can specify extra search paths for the library with `-L`:

```
gcc abc.c -L path_to_directory -lad
```

Comment: i tried with these, but the following error is coming.library -lad not found.fatal:id:not found.collect2: some error came , i don't remember exactly

Comment: @user87627 Where is the file `libad.a`, try to copy in the exact message. Without that it is just guesswork what might be wrong.